# Vector operation

Tags: c++, vector

I have been trying to initialize an array using vector in C++ and inserting values to it. When I compile the code I get the error as mentioned below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Complete the hourglassSum function below.
int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
  int i,j;
  int sum=0;
  vector<int> vect[16];
  vect.insert(vect.begin(),3,5);
  return 0;
}
```

> **Solution.cpp: In function 'int hourglassSum(std::vector >)':
>
> Solution.cpp:17:6: error: request for member 'insert' in 'vect', which
>   is of non-class type 'std::vector [16]'
>
> vect.insert(vect.begin(),3,5);
>
> Solution.cpp:17:18: error: request for member 'begin' in 'vect', which
>   is of non-class type 'std::vector [16]'
>
> vect.insert(vect.begin(),3,5);**
>                     ^~~~~

Comment: Why did you declare an array of vectors vector<int> vect[16];? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically I am trying to declare an array of length 16 and then insert 5 three times from the front into the array.

Comment: Then declare an array of integers.

Comment: vect is not a vector. It's an array of vectors. You can use insert method on any of its items.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: What is the actual problem you try to solve? Why do you need to do this? What is the purpose of the vector, or a possible array of vectors? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since your question is one.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude for your answer below. It helped.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
vector<int> vect[16];
```

you define `vect` to be an array of 16 different (and empty) vectors. If you want a single vector with 16 elements you should do

```
vector<int> vect(16);
```

Note that then if you use `vect.insert(...)` you will add elements to the vector, changing its size from `16`. To solve this either don't use more than the 16 elements you created and use e.g. `vect[i]` (for a valid index `i`), or create an empty vector and use `vect.emplace_back(...)`.

---

If you really want an array, with a fixed size known at compile-time, then maybe use `std::array` instead:

```
array<int, 16> vect;  // Creates an array of 16 int elements
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate on your Note. I wanted to insert elements into vector sequentially using for loop.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur With `vector<int> vect(16);` you define a vector of 16 `int` elements, all initialized to `0`. Inserting another element will make the vector contain 17 elements. If you want to "sequentially add elements" start with a single empty vector (i.e. `vector<int> vect;`).

Comment: I wanted to add elements to the index of vector like we insert in array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to the clarification by the OP in the comments:

what you need is a `vector`/`array` of `int` you can declare one with :

```
std::vector<int> v(16, 0);
```

`v` is a vector with `16` elements initialized to `0`.
then you want to change the first `3` elements to `5`, you can use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) for this:

```
std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, 5);
```

including `<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are bad practice. please avoid them.

and the 
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/FE3xyW)